# Getting a second TableView to show content, error is counting size

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

Using Xcode 6.1, main.Storyboard

I am working with a practice problem in my book, two table views, one goes to the other. I can get all this to work out to two outcomes: (1) It moves to the second table but is empty (2) NSException error IF I keep the code below in it:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return departments.count;
}
```

I am not seeing what is connecting these. In the first one it gives the self.objects, but copying this format with the new array is not working out. Is it related to a changing array size in the second case? Why is it not seeing what I ask it?

```
2014-11-28 19:52:22.477 oc11p5[33625:1199663] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116
2014-11-28 19:52:22.479 oc11p5[33625:1199663] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Since it is this one causing issues, I am just placing these two files:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize selectionH;
@synthesize departments;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (selectionH==0){
        departments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
    }

    else if (selectionH == 1){
        departments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", nil];
    }
    else{
        departments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Yellow", @"Blue", nil];
    }


}



- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
[departments insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}



//vCausing Issue
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return departments.count;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDate *object = departments[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
return cell;
 }





@end
```

and the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property int selectionH;
@property NSMutableArray * departments;

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by this: "one goes to the other"? And this: "It moves to the second table but is empty"? And this: "In the first one it gives the self.objects"? And this: "Why is it not seeing what I ask it"? Your question's really unclear right now...

Comment: what if you do [departemnts count];  what is the actual error  or should be [self.departments count];

Comment: Okay so if you select one of the three cells from the first table view controller, a segue goes to show the second table view controller. When this happens, no cells are filled in the second table view. This is what I am asking about, why will it show up empty, what is causing that?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException ...

Changing form as you suggested leads to the same issue

Comment: departments is set to array of string but in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you set it to NSDate.  That wouldn't work or i am missing something.  Also try the [departments count];

Comment: Changing form to [departments count] as you suggested leads to the same issue.

The date part is as it was working in the first tableViewController. I did try to change it, but it did not work out.

Comment: Add NSLog(@"departments %@", departments);  in numbersOfRowInSection to see what it is holding

Comment: It is holding the array selected. Realized I gave the bottom part of the error though, here's more:

2014-11-28 19:52:22.477 oc11p5[33625:1199663] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116
    2014-11-28 19:52:22.479 oc11p5[33625:1199663] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your cell identifier is set.  For example you can set it to Departments Cell so then the code would look like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Departments Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//NSDate *object = departments[indexPath.row];  There is an issue with this code
cell.textLabel.text = departments[indexPath.row]; //you can set the text this way
return cell;
 }
```

[image]

Post back if that works.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! It seems I still miss a lot of very simple things. I should have noticed that the string meant to find it's name and give it one... Thanks for your patience in helping me. :]

Comment: Glad i was able to help.  Happy Coding! :)